# Product Category Database

Tags: categories, product, categorization

I am looking for openly available data for all or most of  the products that are available in the US , or a good sample of them mapped to their categories. It seems the probability of finding such data is remote but I thought I would check with the folks at stackoverflow, any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon and Ebay offer freely available APIs for product query by category. This is not quite what you are asking for but it may allow you to create a "good sample" of products by category.

https://go.developer.ebay.com/developers/ebay/products/finding-api

https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html

Comment: Thanks Niraj for the excellent infor provided by you ,I guess I will need to query on each category to find the products that match those categories. Do you happen to know if these APIs have a publicly available endpoint to consume the data from on the web ?